# can't make deployment because of .cmp error

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, deployment

I'm trying to deploy a custom lightning component into my salesforce org but it's giving me the following error:

**CPQ_CPQOrderCICMP.cmp c.CPQ_CPQOrderCICMP: org.auraframework.util.json.JsonStreamReader$JsonStreamParseException: Expected ':', found '(' [48, 14]**

This is my .cmp code:

```
<!--
@description Lightning component for NE__OrderItem__c records management [applies for CPQ_Order NE__Order__c records only]
@author Pablo de Andrés
@date 18/07/2019
-->
<aura:component controller="CPQ_CPQOrderManagement" implements="force:hasRecordId,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" extends="c:BI_LEX_HelperComponent">
<aura:attribute name="columns" type="List"/>
<aura:attribute name="expandedRows" type="List"/>
<aura:attribute name="isLoading" type="Boolean"/>
<aura:attribute name="selectedRows" type="List" description="List of selected rows from treegrid"/> 
<aura:attribute name="tgdata" type="Object" description="Data to display into treegrid. Filtered"/>    
<aura:attribute name="labelByFieldNameMAP" type="Map" description="Label by fieldName Map for columns and buttons display"/>
<aura:attribute name="data" type="Object" description="Full data. Use this variable to filter data and assign into tgdata for display"/>
<aura:attribute name="picklistMAP" type="Map" description="Map of fieldName and label for options => Parse response and put into options attribute"/>

<!-- Attributes for action management -->
<aura:attribute name="disableSend" type="Boolean" default="true"/>
<aura:attribute name="disableEdit" type="Boolean" default="true"/>
<aura:attribute name="options" type="List" description="Options for filter select"/>

<lightning:overlayLibrary aura:id="modalLib"/>
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
<aura:handler event="c:CPQ_CPQOrderLinesEVT" action="{!c.handleExternalEvent}"/>

<div class="slds-box boxFaker">
        <div>
            <!-- Loading data or operation management-->
            <aura:if isTrue="{!v.isLoading}">
                <div class="slds-is-relative slds-p-top_large slds-p-bottom_large">
                    <lightning:spinner variant="brand" size="medium" />
                </div>
            </aura:if>
            <!-- Actions to manage -->
            <lightning:layout verticalAlign="end" class="slds-form slds-form_horizontal">
                <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-small" size="2" flexibility="auto">
                    <lightning:combobox aura:id="pacombobox" label="Filtro estado" options="{!v.options}" onchange="{!c.handleComboboxChange}" disabled="{!or(v.tgdata == null, v.tgdata == undefined, v.isLoading)}"/>
                </lightning:layoutItem>
                <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-small" size="3" flexibility="auto">
                    <lightning:button label="Enviar" iconName="utility:internal_share" iconPosition="left" variant="brand" disabled="{!or(v.tgdata == null, v.tgdata == undefined, v.isLoading, v.disableSend)}" onclick="{!c.handleSendCIs}"/>
                </lightning:layoutItem>
                <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-small" size="3" flexibility="auto">
                    <!-- TO DO => make functionality later on / 18/07/2019 -->
                    <lightning:button label="Modificar estado" iconName="utility:edit" iconPosition="left" variant="brand" disabled="{!or(v.tgdata == null, v.tgdata == undefined, v.isLoading, v.disableEdit)}" onclick="{!c.handleStatusChange}"/>
                </lightning:layoutItem>
            </lightning:layout>
            <!-- Treegrid -->
            <aura:if isTrue="{!and(v.tgdata != null, v.tgdata != undefined)}">
                    <lightning:treeGrid
                        keyField="Id"
                        class="tgmheight"
                        data="{!v.tgdata}"
                        aura:id="patreegrid"
                        columns="{!v.columns}"
                        expandedRows="{!v.expandedRows}"
                        onrowselection="{c.handleRowSelection}"/>
                <!-- No data to display-->
                <aura:set attribute="else">
                        <div class="slds-m-around_medium slds-align_absolute-center relevantText">No se encontraron datos</div>
                </aura:set>
            </aura:if>
        </div>
</div>
```

I tried removing .css, .js and .helper but still gives me the error. Also try removing everything from .cmp but no difference.

**What it's causing this?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add the .js side of your component ?

Comment: @FabienHuot I actually found the error => it was caused by the helper. Now it's working!

Answer (score 1):

I actually found it was caused by bad implementation of a function inside .helper.
Now it's working fine.